# Finding the number of combinations under group restrictions

Tags: combinatorics, combinations

Suppose I have 4 instruments, which ranges from 0-100 with steps of 25.

For example, Instrument 1 can have 5 scenarios, 0, 25, 50, 75, 100
Similarly, instruments 2-4 can also have same scenarios.
Now, to find out the combined scenarios of 4 instruments, there can be 5^4=625 scenarios.

However, is there any formula to find out the combined number of scenarios under a constraint that the total of all scenarios will not exceed 100?

That is if instrument 1 has 100, other instruments have to be 0, and likewise.

For example, I manually calculated the total number of scenarios to be 70 for 4 instruments.

Is there any method to calculated these restricted scenarios for n number of instruments?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for a number of solutions of equation:

$a+b+c+d=4$

...with each variable being an integer between 0 and 4 (inclusive). Multiply each solution with 25 and you get your instruments readings.

This is a well known ”[Stars and Bars](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_(combinatorics))” problem. Your problem is described under “Theorem Two”.

The solution is $\binom{n+k-1}{k}$ for $n=k=4$ which is $\binom74=\binom73=35$.

Comment: Thanks. What about if one of the instruments habe different number of scenarios? For example, we are still talking 4 instruments, however, 3 of them can have 5 scenarios but one of them can have say 11 scenarios.